# Trouble with BeanValidation

Tags: bean-validation, jersey-2.0

I am trying to follow the example in https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e13678, esp. section 18.4.3. I want to disallow json where Foo.number is missing. But my test returns status 200. Here is the full text of my test (I do have the jersey-bean-validation artifact in my pom):

```
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;


public class DeleteMe extends JerseyTest {
    @Path("/")
    public static class Resource {
        @POST
        @Produces("application/json")
        public Foo post(@Valid Foo foo) {
            return foo;
        }
    }
    public static class Foo {
       @NotNull
       private Integer number;

       public void setNumber(final Integer number) {
         this.number = number;
       }
       public Integer getNumber() {
         return number;
       }
    }
    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(Resource.class)
                .register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureClient(final ClientConfig config) {
        config.register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }
    @Test
    public void testEntityFail() throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Response response = target().request().post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.json(foo));
       //I get 200 here...but foo is no good
        assertTrue("Status "+response.getStatus(),response.getStatus() == 400);
     }
}
```

Comment: (Plus 1).. This is how all Jersey questions should be asked.. with a runnable test :-). But problem is.. I can't reproduce the problem :-(.. I am getting the expected 400 with your test. What versions and Test server provider are you using? I'm using 2.22.2 with in-memory provider (though I doubt they make a difference)

Comment: Thanks peeskillet. This was a PEBKAC. I updated the pom to include the artifact but the fetch from maven central had failed. It didn't cause a compile time error so I didn't notice it. Once I clean packaged it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

PEBKAC -- I will leave the question up in case someone is getting started with validation and needs a dumbed-down "Hello World" test